# mongodb aggregation object id type chage string to objectId

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

i am currently using 3.0 mongodb version and in this convert,toObject and many more accumulator not supported.
is there any other solution ?

Comment: You can write a script and execute it on mongo shell

Comment: Why do you use an 8 years old and unsupported version of MongoDB?

Comment: full project is already built on 3.0 version at that time so